# What do I do with all the items I pick up?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

During the game, I have picked up various items (amber relics, golden skulls, and a couple of other things) that all seem to do a whole lot of nothing for me.

What do I need them for? I assume they have a use, I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similarly like the bugs, you can use the treasures to upgrade your items at the **Scrap Shop** in the Bazaar or sell them to **Rupin**, the **Gear Shop** owner at night.

To upgrade your items, go to the **Gondo**, the **Scrap Shop** owner at the Bazaar to see which items can be upgraded.  He will list which treasures you need and how much rupees it costs to upgrade an item.

Otherwise you could sell your treasures to **Rupin**, the **Gear Shop** (where you can buy shields) owner at his home at night.  He will only offer to buy 4 different treasures from you at any given night.  So if he doesn't want to buy a certain treasure you want to sell, come see him another time and he'll probably be buying.

Comment: The blacksmith in the bazaar? Oh, that would just make sense, wouldn't it. *sigh*

Comment: This might be a really lame follow up - where in the bazaar is he?

Comment: He's the guy next to one of the exits just next to the item check girl, across from the fortune teller.  There should be an area behind him that you could go in to with one of the goddess chests nearby.

Comment: Oh, now I see him. I wondered what he did, but I was on my way to do something else, so I never bothered to check. Silly me!