# What items can I upgrade in Skyward Sword?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I [just learned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42269/what-do-i-do-with-all-the-items-i-pick-up) that all the bits and bobs I pick up can upgrade my items.

What are all the items that I can upgrade? I want the best of the best, after all. What do I need to do each upgrade?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a list of what every item requires for upgrade [on this page](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-upgrades.php).

The short list is:

- Shields, each one has 3 levels and can be upgraded at the scrap shop.
- Ammo carrying containers, each has 3 levels and can be upgraded at the scrap shop
- Potions can also be upgraded.  Health and Revitalizing Potions have 3 levels, and at the third it will completely restore you twice.  Stamina, Air, and Guardian potions have two levels, with the second level being more effective than the first.

Additionally, you can upgrade the Beetle, the Bug Net, the Bow, the Mitts (although the upgrade is part of a dungeon treasure, and not via collectable items), and the Slingshot.

There are also additional wallets available for purchase, although calling them "upgrades" might be a stretch.

Comment: Actually, the wallets are not really upgradable in the game, you can just buy extra wallets or find larger capacity ones.  Subtle but an important difference.

Comment: The Mitts aren't upgraded in the shop, either; you acquire a new version later, but you don't use the Vendor Trash to do it the way you do the other items, which is what the asker is asking about.